# Posting image from expo and axios to spring boot server returns error

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, axios

I wanna send an `axios` request with photo data to my `Spring Boot` server but it does not work.
Here is the code:

```
const updateUserProfile = dispatch => async ({categories, phoneNumber, photo}) => {
    try {
        const id = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('user_id');
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("file", {
            uri: photo,
            name: `${id}_photo`,
            type: 'image/png'
        })
        
        await request.post(
            `/photos/${id}`,
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
                },
            },
        )

        dispatch({type: 'update_user_profile', payload: response.data})
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_ERROR'})
    }
}
```

The file `URI` looks like that and I think its correct:

```
file:///data/user/0/[...]/ImagePicker/e9255306-dca9-486e-a9
05-e4e1c619b766.jpg
```

And here is the `Spring Boot` `Controller`

```
    @PostMapping("/{userId}")
    public void saveObject(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable Long userId) {
        photoService.uploadFile(file, userId);
    }
```

Spring Boot works great when I send request with photo from `postman` but when I want to send the request from `updateUserProfile` method above, I receive this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the file as  a 'file' from axios. I mean something like:                              ```const file = event.target.files[0]                                                                                       
 const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("file", file
        )```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally after many hours I fixed the problem. This `github issue` helped me a lot https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4412

So I installed `form-data` package

```
npm i form-data
```

and in the `updateUserProfile` method added this line  just before appending data to `formData`

```
FormData.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'FormData';
```

so the full method looks like that now:

```
const updateUserProfile = dispatch => async ({categories, phoneNumber, photo}) => {
    try {
        const id = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('user_id');
        const extenstion = photo.substring(photo.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
        const fileName = photo.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
        const formData = new FormData()
        
        FormData.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'FormData';
        formData.append("file", {
            uri: photo,
            name: fileName,
            type: `image/${extenstion}`
        })
        
        await request.post(
            `/photos/${id}`,
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
                },
            },
        )

        dispatch({type: 'update_user_profile', payload: response.data})
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_ERROR'})
    }
}
```